# ScreenShot as Button content

Tags: wpf

I want to do something similar to Microsoft Powerpoint: I want to capture the current screen (or one grid from the current window), and then to set it as the content of the button (like powerpoint where there is a preview of the slides at the side bar).

What is the best way to do that? My current idea is to save it to PNG and then reload it as an image at the content of the button, but I'm sure there is a better way.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
    <Grid>
        <Viewbox 
            x:Name="Viewer" 
            Stretch="Uniform"
            DataContext="{Binding ElementName=Thumbnail1, Path=Data}">
            <Grid Width="224" Height="168" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Margin="4,0,4,0">
                <Grid.Background>
                    <VisualBrush Stretch="Uniform" TileMode="None" Visual="{Binding}" AlignmentY="Center"/>
                </Grid.Background>
            </Grid>
        </Viewbox>
    </Grid>
```

I was using saving as PNG approach in the beginning. Then I have found out the way as above. DataContext of the ViewBox is a canvas. I could create live previews of my screens this way however my screens were canvas objects.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I want to do this at code (When I click save). How I do the binding part at code? 
I am using canvas also.

Comment: Put this Grid as a content of your button that will show the thumbnail. When you click your save button you can set Viewer.DataContext = YourCanvas; If you prefer binding in code behind try: var BindingInstance = new Binding("YourCanvas") {                Mode = OneWay }; 
Viewer.SetBinding(FrameworkElement.DataContextProperty, BindingInstance);

Comment: It works, but I decided to go with PNG because I have canvas and BingMaps. Thank you!